# Reusable form choices in symfony2 forms

Tags: forms, symfony

I have the following code that's working... but I think it can be done better.

(Description below).

```
Class Address
{
    protected province;

    public function getProvince()...
}

class AddressType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        ...
        $build->add(Province, new ProvinceType());
        ...
    }
}

class ProvinceType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $provinceList = array(... //very long list
        ...
        $build->add(Province, 'choice', array(
        'choices' => $provinceList;
        ));

   public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Acme\Bundle\Entity\Address'
        ));
    }
}

class PersonType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $Province = array(... //very long list
        ...
        $build->add('Address', new AddressType());
        $build->add('FromProvince', new AddressType());
    }
}
```

I have two problems with the code above:

1. Using this in twig PersonType form I have to do `form_widget(person.Address.ProvinceType.ProvinceType)` to use it. This just looks so wrong.
2. To validate the province I have to go one method deeper than I should have to.

In the end I just want to be able to validate fields that make sense such as:

```
Acme\Bundle\Entity\Person:
    property:
        provinceBorn:
            - NotBlank: ~ //Wish to reuse province list here for straight-forward validation.
        Address:
            Valid: ~

Acme\Bundle\Entity\Address:
    property:
        province:
            - NotBlank: ~ //As well as here.
```

Answer (score 0):

To shorten the path to your `ProvinceType`, you should maybe define it as a base widget that would extend Symfony's `choice` type (see [the doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html) on this). The best you'd get here would be something like `{{ form_widget(person.address.province) }}`.

To make choices reusable, it would be smart to extract your `ProvinceType` into a service (see [Symfony's doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#defining-your-forms-as-services) on how to do this) and pass the list of provinces as a parameter into the `ProvinceType`'s `__construct` method (that would be defined in your bundle's `services.yml`). That way you would be able to extract your provinces into an external storage.

On validation, keep in mind that the YAML you've supplied here has mostly nothing to do with Form component, it's about your entity. So, duplicating `NotBlank` constraints actually makes sense, because you're not linking `Person`'s `provinceBorn` property to an `Address` entity, you're saving a separate field.

Though, if you define a custom field type, you can make it required by default by moving the constraint into the `Type` you extracted to a service. Such constraint can be defined like this:

```
<?php

class ProvinceChoiceType extends AbstractType
{

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([ 
            'constraints' => [
                new NotBlank(['message' => 'Title is required']),
            ],
        ]);
    }

...
```

Comment: The thing is that the first argument for `$builder->add` needs to be a getter name. And I'm using two different entities. The `Person` getter is `setProvinceBorn` and `Address` entity `setProvince`. But I'm thinking I can do the construct portion like you said and inject it into different choice types for each entity... I like that idea.

Answer (score 0):

I have done the something similar in this way (I'll use your example):

```
    Class Address
{
    protected province;

    public function getProvince()...
}

class AddressType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
            $provinceList = array(... //very long list

            ...
        $build->add('province', 'choice', array(
            'choices' => $provinceList, 'empty_value' => null, 'required' => true,
        ));
        ...
    }
}

class PersonType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $Province = array(... //very long list
        ...
        $build->add('address', new AddressType());
        $build->add('fromProvince', new AddressType());
    }
}
```

And you send the data:

```
    ...
    $form   = $this->createForm(new PersonType(), $entity);

    return array(
        'form'     => $editForm->createView(),
    );
```

And use this in Twig as below:

```
{{ form_widget(form.address.province) }}
```

Finally, I think your validation are correct, but if you need something more specific, you could use the getters method as in the Symfony documentation is specified, in the validation section http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html#getters

Comment: Right, the thing is for the other field I'll have to do. `form.fromProvince.address.getProvince` instead of what I want which is `form.fromProvince`

Answer (score 0):

Extended answer from before with explanations.

Inheriting form
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/inherit_data_option.html

## Code

With your code it should look something like this

```
class AddressType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        ...
        $build->add(Province, new ProvinceType(), [
            'inherit_data' => true 
             // this is an alterrnative for having it bellow inside configure options
             // use one or another, what suit you better
        ]);
        ...
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
         $resolver->setDefaults([
             'inherit_data' => true
         ]);
    }
    // in sf > 2.7 use public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
}

class ProvinceType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $provinceList = array(... //very long list
        ...
        $build->add(Province, 'choice', array(
            'choices' => $provinceList;
        ));

   public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Acme\Bundle\Entity\Address',
            'inherit_data' => true
        ));
    }
}

class PersonType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $Province = array(... //very long list
        ...
        $build->add('Address', new AddressType());
        $build->add('FromProvince', new AddressType());
    }
}
```

This you addressType inherits fields from provinceType, and PersonType inherits from both addressType (including its inherited fields from provinceType).

## Template

So it should be possible to do this inside template

```
 {{ form_row(form.Province)}}
```

## Validation

The best way would be to so validation constrains on your relations with the Valid constrain.
This will force the validations on the children also
http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Valid.html

The other option is setting cascade_validation on the form, but this wont forward your validation groups if any.

Either way, you would then need define validation only on each entity once.